# raise EOFError('Compressed file ended before the " EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached')

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

Every time I try to run my program that uses fashion_mnist, it returns this error:

`raise EOFError('Compressed file ended before the " EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached')`

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

shoe = "shoe.png"

fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

predictions = model.predict(shoe)
```

I tried reinstalling tensorflow to see if I just had an outdated version of it, but that didn't work

After that, I tried reinstalling the fashion_mnist dataset. This didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string to predict() instead of an image array. Please load the image and convert it to an array first. Then pass it to the predict() method like below

```
shoe=tf.keras.utils.load_img("/content/shoe.jpeg")
shoe=tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(shoe)
shoe=tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(shoe)
shoe=np.resize(shoe,(1, 28,28,1))
predictions=model.predict(shoe)
print(predictions)
```

Also, You must compile your model before training/testing.

```
model.compile('adam','sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics='acc' )
```

Please find the working code [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/gist/synandi/f3f0b42f952036dc399812485afbcd5a/74756372.ipynb).Thank you!